# Concrete Noun or Abstract Noun

Tags: nouns, abstract-nouns, concrete-nouns

I recently had to identify what type of noun "happiness" is in the following sentence:

You could feel happiness and joy in the air

The listed options were:

Possessive
Collective
Concrete

"concrete" was stated as correct answer.

Despite this apparently being the correct answer, as far as I can tell this is incorrect as it's surely abstract? I would argue that despite being able to feel the effects of happiness, it's in no way tangible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I agree. Have you taken it up with the author of the test?

Comment: It seems like a trick question. A "concrete" noun is something that exists in the physical world; happiness and joy are abstract concepts; however, in the example, happiness and joy are described (metaphorically) as physical objects that can be felt in the air.